# VueJS pushing route with params shows old params in browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, browser-history

**Scenario**

I've a app where I use `vue.js 2.6` and `vue-router 3.0`

in there I've links to detail pages like this

```
<div v-for="item in items">
    <router-link  :to="{name: 'details', params: {key: item.shortKey}}">
</div>
```

**what works**

Now in the target view the parameter always has the correct value
Also when I first time click a link then I see the correct shortkey in the browser.

**Not working**

Now when I click another itemm I still see in the browser url the key of the item that was clicked first in the browser . Eventhough inside the code the route.params do have the correct value.

Both the View browser tools  and the code itself have the correct value.
What am I missing?

Also using `router.push` has the same result. Changing from `history` to `hash` mode also doesn't change the behavior

**Shortened Router config**

```
const routes = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    component: layout,
    path: '/',
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home,
        meta:{display:"home"}
      },
      {
        path:'list',
        name:'list',
        component: listItemsComponent,
      },

      {
        path: 'details/:key',
        name: 'details',
        component: detailComponent
      },
    ]
  }]
});
```

Comment: what do you mean ? I can see that the url in the href in the dom are containing all the same url pointing to the first item. But clicking it shows the correct item.

Manually typing the url in the browser always works

Comment: Can you replicate this in a fiddle?

Comment: @BoasEnkler Most probably you need to force a replacement using the `key` attribute in the `router-view` component. ie. `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a unique key to each element in v-for like below -

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <router-link  :to="{name: 'details', params: {key: item.shortKey}}">
</div>
```

As per vue js docs,

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus
>   reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key
>   attribute for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add '/' in your path : `path: '/details/:key'`